# Why can't I star this chat message?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

I tried to star [this chat message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9022873#9022873) but the star immediately goes away and I get a message "It is too late to undo this operation". Staring other messages works fine.

[image: video showing "It is too late to undo this operation" when attempting to star a message]

Comment: My guess would be that a Room Owner cleared the stars on that message

Comment: Also note that the message apparently doesn't only pop up when stars were cleared by a room owner: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278138/369802 It apparently can also happen if you yourself have starred and unstarred something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cleared the stars on the message because I didn't think it needed to be on the starboard. You cannot re-star a message that you had previously starred after stars have been cleared, but the error message given doesn't really explain it well.